# Show select field if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, html

Good day, I'm having a bit trouble of how can I show the select field if the check box is checked

```
  <div class="checkbox">
    <br>
    <label style="padding-right:0px;"><input type="checkbox" name="cod" value="1" > My shop offers <b>Cash on Delivery</b></label>
  </div>

     <select name="" id="" style="padding-left:0px;">
          <option value="">Around Metro Manila Only</option>
          <option value="">Outside Metro Manila Only</option>
          <option value="">Both</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: if checkbox checked which option should be selected??

Comment: @devpro I just want to show the select box

Comment: select box will display in default or hide? did u checked my solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> You must have `id` attribute to the `select` input element to identify the element and use it as `jQuery` selector.

`.change()` will trigger `change` event on the checkbox and invoke the handler,  which will show/hide the select input initially.

**Edit:** Use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) Display or hide the matched elements. Boolean argument will decide the visibility of the matched elements.

```js
$('[name="cod"]').on('change', function() {
  $('#select').toggle(this.checked);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <br>
  <label style="padding-right:0px;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cod" value="1">My shop offers <b>Cash on Delivery</b>
  </label>
</div>

<select name="" style="padding-left:0px;" id='select'>
  <option value="">Around Metro Manila Only</option>
  <option value="">Outside Metro Manila Only</option>
  <option value="">Both</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how can i make the select field hide first ? even I removed the checked the select field still shows in default

Comment: anyway this is nice explanation, after your update.. :)

Answer (score 5):

here is Solution of your problem please check this

**css**

```
select.selectDrop{
  display:none;
}
```

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="seeds" value="Indigofera" /> <span> My shop offers <b>Cash on Delivery</b></span> 


     <select class="selectDrop" name="" id="" style="padding-left:0px;">
          <option value="">Around Metro Manila Only</option>
          <option value="">Outside Metro Manila Only</option>
          <option value="">Both</option>
      </select>
```

**jquery**

```
$('[type="checkbox"][name="seeds"]').change(function(){
  $('select.selectDrop').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

**Here's the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfS2u/14/) example.**

Comment: The only issue with this solution is if checkbox is checked, it will still not show the select. `Trigger` will help!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use toggle event, if checkbox checked display the select box else hide.

> Note that, you need to use id attribute for select box
>   `id="selectBox"`

**Example:**

```js
$('[name="cod"]').click(function() {
    $("#selectBox").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
<br>
<label style="padding-right:0px;"><input type="checkbox" name="cod" value="1" > My shop offers <b>Cash on Delivery</b></label>
</div>

<select name="" id="selectBox" style="padding-left:0px;display:none;">
  <option value="">Around Metro Manila Only</option>
  <option value="">Outside Metro Manila Only</option>
  <option value="">Both</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @JonasDulay: glad to help u.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <div class="checkbox">
<br>
<label style="padding-right:0px;"><input type="checkbox" name="cod" value="1" > My shop offers <b>Cash on Delivery</b></label>
```

```
<?php $test=$_GET['test']?>
 <select name="test" id="" style="padding-left:0px;">
      <option <?php if($test==1) echo 'selected'?> value="1">Around Metro Manila Only</option>
      <option <?php if($test==2) echo 'selected'?> value="2">Outside Metro Manila Only</option>
      <option <?php if($test==3) echo 'selected'?> value="3">Both</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which option you want to select but you can alter the .selectedIndex value to change that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="checkbox">
    <br>
    <label style="padding-right:0px;"><input type="checkbox" name="cod" value="1" onclick="selectItem(this.checked)"> My shop offers <b>Cash on Delivery</b></label>
  </div>

     <select name="" id="myList" style="padding-left:0px;">
          <option value="">Around Metro Manila Only</option>
          <option value="">Outside Metro Manila Only</option>
          <option value="">Both</option>
      </select>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function selectItem(isChecked){
    if(isChecked){
        document.getElementById('myList').selectedIndex=1;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('myList').selectedIndex=0;
    }
}
</script>
```